# An empty JSON can pass the validation of model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While testing my mobile application, I tried to pass an empty JSON to create the record of students:

```
  Parameters: {"student"=>{}}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "students" ("course_id", "created_at", "icon", "name", "password", "status", "studentID", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["course_id", nil], ["created_at", Mon, 08 Oct 2012 13:07:12 UTC +00:00], ["icon", nil], ["name", nil], ["password", nil], ["status", "pending"], ["studentID", nil], ["updated_at", Mon, 08 Oct 2012 13:07:12 UTC +00:00]]
   (3.5ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Student Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "students" WHERE ("students"."studentID" IS NULL AND "students"."id" != 46) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 61ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 5.2ms)
```

My model validates the presence of certain fields:

```
validates :name, :password, :status, :studentID, :presence =>true
  validate :validate_course_id
  validates :studentID, :uniqueness=>{:message=>"This studentID already exists"}
```

Although the JSON is empty, it will create a record with almost all of the fields null, except `created_at`, `updated_at`, and `pending`.

In the controller:

```
  def create
    @student = Student.new(params[:student])
    # @student.update_attribute(:status,'pending')
    @student.status = 'pending'

    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.save
        upload_icon(params[:student][:icon_upload])

        format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @student, status: :created, location: @student }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `update_attribute`:

Updates a single attribute and saves the record without going through the normal validation procedure. This is especially useful for boolean flags on existing records. The regular `update_attribute` method in Base is replaced with this when the validations module is mixed in, which it is by default.

For `update_attributes`:

Updates all the attributes from the passed-in Hash and saves the record. If the object is invalid, saving will fail and false will be returned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and people who edited my problem statement:)
I really appreciate you can understand my reply. I was so sleepy to reply yesterday. I have also posted the create method in controller :)